# Написать метод, который позоволит получить информацию о данном каталоге

Tags: java

Дано:Каталог на диске (например: "D:/new")

```
  File file = new File("D:/new");

       File[] a = file.listFiles();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i]);

        }:
```

как проверить количество файлов внутри данного каталога с учетом всех вложенных каталогов

Comment: Отличный пример http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-recursively-display-all-files-and-directories-in-a-directory.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте рекурсивный метод обхода:

- получить список элементов каталога
- если элемент - директория - получить список его элементов и т. д.